# How I restore backup data?

Tags: shell, rsync, backup

I am completely new to the field and have a question about restoring my data from a Debian server,

I have saved my data via rsync on a second server. For example the complete /etc/ folder.

Now my question, can I now just copy the /etc/ folder from the backup to a new server with a newly set up operating system and delete the /etc/ folder from the new server first?

Or does the whole thing not work like that?

Comment: The `/etc` directory contains specific configuration for the current machine.  This may not be the correct configuration for your new server and may, if the backed-up server is still alive and running, cause two machines to have the same IP addresses, the same SSH host keys and other things that should be configured individually for each machine.  The `/etc` directory is special in that sort of way, and it's unclear if you picked this only as an example or not.

Comment: A backup is just a backup.  I.e., a snapshot in time of the state of some data.  This does not mean that it is suitable as a template for making copies of the  system that the backup was made from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc` directory directly corresponds to the installed packages and and their configuration. Restoring it without restoring all other directories is probably not the best thing to do but certainly can be done.

You cannot just copy files from the backup, you need to restore permissions as well, for instance you cannot leave `/etc/shadow` world-readable as it's a major security risk - this file contains salted passwords which could be recovered if passwords are not sufficiently strong.

Again, in the perfect world you either backup everything on your server sans temporary files or backup only the files and directories which are relevant.